# Unable to call a pointer to function returning a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm stuck with a weird problem.
I have two files a.c and b.c as follows:
b.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *foo() {
  int *x;
  x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *x = 4;
  return x;
}
```

I compile b.c to b.so using gcc:
$ gcc -o b.so -shared -fpic

a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
  void *hdl;
  hdl = dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  int *((*fn)(void));
  int *x;
  x = (*fn)();
  fn = dlsym(hdl, "foo");
  printf("%d", *x);
}
```

I compile a.c using gcc:

$ gcc -fpic -ldl a.c

Now when I run it:

$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault

Where I'm I going wrong?
This works when the function in b.c doesn't return a pointer.

And moreover, I tried checking for errors using dlerror(), but it reports none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By inspection, you are using `fn` before you have initialized it. It doesn't yet point to `foo`, it doesn't yet point to anything in particular, and I suspect the resultant behavior is undefined.

Comment: Initialized (or assigned a value to it), not defined. The variable `fn` is defined prior to its usage.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: Sie haben recht, danke.

Answer (score 4):

You are not finding the symbol and calling the function.

When you do `x = (*fn)();` it doesnt make call to the function `foo` from `b.c`.

You have to first get the symbol loaded into your function pointer.

```
  int *x;
  fn = dlsym(hdl, "foo");
  x = fn();
  printf("%d", *x);
```

The above should work.

EDIT:

Sample program for dlopen,dlsym can be found [here](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/x172.html) with man page info for the same.

Comment: I used the same source to learn how to generate .so files and use them :)

Answer (score 3):

Could be just a problem with your example, but in the code you provide, you need to switch the following lines:

```
 x = (*fn)();
fn = dlsym(hdl, "foo");
```

Answer (score 3):

These two lines appear to be in the wrong order:

```
x = (*fn)();
fn = dlsym(hdl, "foo");
```